# How to return value in orElse in Optional?

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream, option-type

I have Optional object

```
Optional<Instrument> instrument = instrumentService.findOne(id);
```

And i have two scenario. First return ResponseEntity.ok if object is present and second is return ResponseEntity.noContent().build().
I have function

```
instrument.map(instrument1 -> {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(instrumentMapper.toDto(instrumentRepository.save(instrument1)));
        })
        .//return noContent here;
```

What i need to write after dot to return necessary part?

Comment: use `orElseGet(() -> ResponseEntity.no Content().build())`

Comment: you need to start writing with the API that you want to use `orElse` first and then see what arguments does it accept as values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `orElse`:

```
return instrument
    .map(instrument1 -> instrument1 -> { 
        instrument1.setValue(value); 
        return ResponseEntity.ok(instrumentMapper.toDto(instrumentRepository.save(instrument1))); })
    .orElse(ResponseEntity.noContent().build());
```

And for further building the default value:

```
return instrument
    .map(instrument1 -> instrument1 -> { 
        instrument1.setValue(value); 
        return ResponseEntity.ok(instrumentMapper.toDto(instrumentRepository.save(instrument1))); })
    .orElseGet(() -> {
        Intrument inst = new Intrument(); 
        inst.setTitle("Not found"); 
        return inst; 
    });
```

Comment: if i have more than one line in map

Comment: for example`map(instrument1 -> { instrument1.setValue(10);
ResponseEntity.ok(instrumentMapper.toDto(instrumentRepository.save(instrument1)));})`

Comment: @Krazim00da I'm not following, that's the code I have provided

Comment: what if i want to manipulatre with data in orElse block?

Comment: The? What if? Do you have an example?

Comment: something like that `return instrument
    .map(instrument1 -> instrument1 -> { 
        instrument1.setValue(value); 
        return instrument1;)
    .orElse(() ->
    Intrument inst = new Intrument();
    inst.setTitle("Not found");
    return inst;
    );`

Comment: @Krazim00da check out my edit